# Converting node.js Jwt example to .Net

Tags: asp.net, node.js, jwt

I am trying to use a web api. They require that I use Jwt tokens. I am trying to do this in a asp.net 4.5.2 web app on azure. I have downloaded the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens Nuget package and would like to use it to generate the needed tokens.

The web api I am trying to use has an example in node.js on how to generate the proper token. Here is their example:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var payload = {
    iss: api_key,
    exp: ((new Date()).getTime() + 5000)
};

//Automatically creates header, and returns JWT
var token = jwt.sign(payload, api_secret);
```

All of the examples for the nuget package do a ton more than what is shown in the node.js example. Things like creating a secret value, claims identity, signing credentials and all kinds of other stuff.

I have the api_key value and the api_secret value. Can someone please tell me how to do the same thing using the nuget package as what they show using node.js?

Comment: Is your api_secret a base64 encoded string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I think I have a solution. This is the simplest it gets in c# unfortunately, but I think its a passable solution considering we are talking apples and oranges. It seems C# is twice as verbose about the options and doesn't have sensible defaults for anything.

```cs
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;


namespace stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String api_key = "apiKey123123";
            String api_secret = "401b09eab3c013d4ca54922bb802bec8fd5318192b0a75f201d8b3727429090fb337591abd3e44453b954555b7a0812e1081c39b740293f765eae731f5a65ed1";

            var signingKey = Convert.FromBase64String(api_secret);

            JwtHeader jwtHeader = new JwtHeader(
               new SigningCredentials(
                   new SymmetricSecurityKey(signingKey),
                   SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature
               )
            );

            JwtPayload jwtPayload = new JwtPayload {
                {"iss", api_key},
                {"exp", ((DateTimeOffset)DateTime.UtcNow).AddMilliseconds(5000).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() }
            };

            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtHeader, jwtPayload);
            var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            Console.Write(jwtHandler.WriteToken(jwt));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Only import was this package:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.2.1" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try and let you know if it works.

Comment: This works with one change. For some reason the api I am using wanted the header.alg to be HS256, but the code you provided has a long url defined for SecurityAlgoritms.HmacSha256Signature. That is ok because I just replaced that with "HS256" and it verifies on jwt.io checker. the api I am using still doesn't authorize, but that must be something else.